# deployment target 5.0 not available in xcode for cordova app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have 2 programs both with xcode 5.1.1 and cordova on one my deployment targets include 5.0 on the other the lowest it goes is 6.0.

I can't seem to see what is the difference is. How do I get the other one to allow me to go down to 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you did not use the same version of cordova to generate the two projects.

[Support for ios 5 has been dropped in codova 3.5](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/05/23/cordova-350.html)
So if you built one project with 3.3 or 3.4, later installed 3.5 and built the other project but did not upgrade the first project, that would explain everything.

To make sure, you can go to each the projects and run the command `cordova platforms ls`

Comment: Might be right.  When I run cordova platforms ls I get             

"Installed platforms: android 3.4.0, ios 3.5.0"   and   "Installed platforms: android 3.5.0, ios 3.5.0"  so I did install it with an older version and one was upgraded the other was installed with the newer version.